# Prevent chef recipe from executing previously executed action?

Tags: chef-solo, chef

I have a simple recipe like the following, and currently I am using a local file to indicate if the command has been run or not

```
execute "test" do
  command "sh test.sh && touch /opt/myapp/done.log"
  only_if {File.exists?("/opt/myapp/done.log")}
end
```

Are there better method? It is the recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally the method I use, especially if the command you take results in a file being created as a side effect  For example disabling or enabling sites in Debian's apache2 package removes or creates links in `/etc/apache2` which you can test for using `File.exists?`.

A trick is to set an attribute after the execute resource has run:

```
if !node["did_test"]
  execute "test" do
    command "touch /tmp/foo"
  end
end

ruby_block "did_test" do
  block do
    node.default["did_test"] = true
  end
end
```

Note that it's still possible for the execute resource to be run twice in some situations so this technique isn't perfect, but you can now use knife-search to determine which nodes have performed the execute.

Comment: Hi, actually what is the differe.nt between your version and my version? Thanks

Comment: I'm using a Chef node attribute to store whether the recipe has been executed or not.  The value of the attribute is stored on the Chef server and can be queried (or modified) using knife.

Answer (score 4):

There are some ways to keep `execute` from running several times on node:

- Using `not_if`, `only_if` statements.
- Using `action :nothing` and then notifying this `execute` resource to run from another resource. (only if you need to run it every time the first resource changes)
- Using `creates [some/file]` (Chef will run it, only if the file does not exist, equivalent to `not_if { ::File.exists? '[some/file]' }`

If you cannot easily determine, if your script has run without creating an additional file, then it is the only way. So you, actually, are doing everything right.

Except that the code you provided will actually run, **if the file exists**. But I suppose that is a typo.